# graph top and bottom scoring teams

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data frame like this

```
Date    Team   Score
1/1/2010 A     10
1/1/2010 B     15
1/1/2010 C     90
1/1/2010 D     100
1/1/2010 E     27
1/1/2010 F     76
1/1/2010 G     10
1/1/2010 H    85
1/1/2010 I     10
1/1/2010 J     5
1/1/2010 K     56
1/1/2010 K     60
1/1/2010 M     15
1/2/2010 A     10
1/2/2010 B     15
1/2/2010 C     90
1/2/2010 D     100
1/2/2010 E     27
1/2/2010 F     76
1/2/2010 G     10
1/2/2010 H    85
1/2/2010 I     10
1/2/2010 J     5
1/2/2010 K     56
1/2/2010 K     60
1/2/2010 M     15
```

etc

I would like to graph the top 5 high scoring teams over the time period and bottom 5 (lowest scoring teams) with ggplot2.

Is it feasible to do this with ggplot? I can graph all the teams but since I have lots of teams, I would like to be able to look at top scorers and low scorers.

any input will be appreciated?

Comment: What type of graph are you thinking (and yes this is very feasible with ggplot2)?

Comment: Yes you can. What have you tried?

Comment: I can use subset to pic score > 80 etc. However, I would like to pick top five teams that scored highest averace score over the time.

Comment: If your data is called dat: `X <- aggregate(Score~Team, dat, mean); Y <- X[order(X$Score), ]; head(Y, 5); tail(Y, 5)`

Comment: thank you so much, this is it. Can you put this as an answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your data is named `dat` to begin with, this basic approach should work:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plyr)

#summarize and subset
plotdat <- ddply(dat, "Team", summarize, meanval = mean(Score))
plotdat <- plotdat[order(plotdat$meanval),]
plotdat <- rbind(head(plotdat,5), tail(plotdat,5))

#Plot
ggplot(plotdat, aes(reorder(Team, meanval), meanval)) + 
  geom_bar() +
  coord_flip() +
  xlab("Team") +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]